# Legenda no comando matplot

Tags: r

Como faço para criar uma legenda no comando matplot?

```
a = rnorm(1000)
b = runif(1000)
matplot(cbind(a, b), type = 'l')
```

Comment: Você usa a mesma função que em um `plot()` normal. Dê uma olhada em `?legend`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma legenda rapidamente com o comando `legend`. Eu fiz uma pequena legenda para o exemplo que você citou:

```
a = rnorm(1000)
b = runif(1000)
matplot(cbind(a, b), type = 'l', ylim=c(-5,5), main = "Séries",
        xlab = 'dias', ylab='contagens')
legend("topright", legend = c('a', 'b'), col = c('red', 'black'),
       ncol = 2, cex = 1, lwd = 2, text.col = c('red', 'black'))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS**

O comando `legend` tem diversas opções e você consegue ver toda a documentação por meio de:

```
??legend
```